# How fix keyboard problem when tableView reloading?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, keyboard

I have a problem with between keyboard and tableview. API calls and getting new data when I clicking on the cell. And the same time when clicking to cell keyboard was open and coming scroll issue in tableview.reloadData(). I'm calling clicking cell -> api calls, getts new data -> tableView reloading -> tableview scrolls to top and later keyboard Willshow function brings cell to keyboard's top (scrolling top later to bottom). How can I fix it?

P.s: each time I must call API.

[image: GifImage]

```
fileprivate func addingNotifications() {
        //Subscribe to a Notification which will fire before the keyboard will show
        subscribeToNotification(UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShowOrHide))

        //Subscribe to a Notification which will fire before the keyboard will hide
        subscribeToNotification(UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShowOrHide))
    }

@objc func keyboardWillShowOrHide(notification: NSNotification) {
            // Get required info out of the notification
        if let scrollView = tableView, let userInfo = notification.userInfo, let endValue = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey], let durationValue = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey], let curveValue = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] {

            // Transform the keyboard's frame into our view's coordinate system
            let endRect = view.convert((endValue as AnyObject).cgRectValue, from: view.window)

            // Find out how much the keyboard overlaps our scroll view
            let keyboardOverlap = scrollView.frame.maxY - endRect.origin.y

            // Set the scroll view's content inset & scroll indicator to avoid the keyboard
            scrollView.contentInset.bottom = keyboardOverlap + 50
            scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = keyboardOverlap + 50

            let duration = (durationValue as AnyObject).doubleValue
            let options = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt((curveValue as AnyObject).integerValue << 16))
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: options, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is triggering the keyboard to come up in the first place? Are there any textfields in this view?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of behavior your are expecting in here,  but if you want to resign/hide keyboard then you can write self.view.endEditing() in tableview will select delegate method(Tells the delegate a row is about to be selected)

Comment: i want never keyboard dismiss and tableview never scroll. but it scrolls to top later to bottom when clicking cell and tableview reloading

Comment: Have you tried this:                                               
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1) as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
self.tableView.endUpdates()

Comment: yes, now tableView scroll problem was fixed, but every cell clicking keyboard dismisses and later comes again. can i keep it?

Comment: Can you please try with self.view.endediting(false)

Comment: not worked:( I added after tableView.reloadData() and before

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue happens in some version of iOS.
You can fix it by using a method `performWithoutAnimation` of `UIView` as the following:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
  self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .none)
}
```